# How get operating system name in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I would like to retrieve the name of the operating system in C ++.
I tried with GetVersionExA which is a windows method. But this method is deprecated.Is there a way to recover the name of the operating system eg "Windows 10 Enterprise" thanks to standard c ++ or with windows or Qt ...?

Comment: Have you read the [Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/getting-the-system-version)?

Comment: @scohe001 yes I read the documentation but I will want the exact version Windows server 8, Windows XP, Windows 10 family ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also [`GetProductInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo) which can show this ENTERPRISE subversion.

Comment: Yes great !!! 
I will get majorversion and minorversion and use this method

Answer (score 4):

Use `QOperatingSystemVersion::current().name()`

Comment: Thank for your answer but I do not have the exact version.

Answer (score 0):

If the operating system is Windows Vista or later, you can use the WMI interface and query on [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with Caption and Version fields (or any other fields of your choice).

Microsoft provides an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer) on how to fetch the data.